# How to make the picture appear in a different place with each click, and not be copied

Tags: ios, swift

When I do long tap, I have an image displayed. And if I make 10 long tapes, then I will display 10 images. And I need to make sure that I make long tap and the image appears, and then I do long tap again and it is displayed, but in a different place and if I make 10 long tap, the image will be displayed on the last long tap.

my code:

```
 @objc func longPressHappened(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
      let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: self.mScrollView)
      let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pimp"))
      imageView.center = CGPoint(x: tapLocation.x, y: tapLocation.y - imageView.frame.height / 2)
      CSImageView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
  }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let longRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressHappened))
    longRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1
    longRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(longRecognizer)
  }
}
```

Tell me how to make such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you are creating a new instance of `UIImageView` instead reuse the same instance of `UIImageView`. So, you need to declare the imageView outside the scope of the function. Here is some code:

```swift
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pimp"))

@objc func longPressHappened(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
      let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: self.mScrollView)
      imageView.center = CGPoint(x: tapLocation.x, y: tapLocation.y - imageView.frame.height / 2)
      CSImageView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```